# How to configure Asterisk `menuselect` build options programmatically?

Tags: bash, asterisk

I am writing a Bash script for installing Asterisk. Instead of running the `make menuselect` command, which provides an interactive UI to select different options, I want to use the command `menuselect/menuselect --enable ____ menuselect.makeopts` to select required options for the build. But when I run the script, I get this error:

> menuselect/menuselect: No such file or directory

How to run this command from a script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a preliminary build with `make menuselect.makeopts` before you can run `menuselect`. Here's what a portion of my build script looks like:

```
pushd /usr/local/src/asterisk-13.5.0/
./configure --libdir=/usr/lib64 --without-dahdi --without-pri --without-gtk2 \
    --without-radius --without-x11 --without-speex --with-pjproject-bundled
make menuselect.makeopts
menuselect/menuselect \
    --disable-category MENUSELECT_ADDONS \
    --disable-category MENUSELECT_APPS \
        --enable app_authenticate --enable app_cdr --enable app_celgenuserevent \
        --enable app_channelredirect --enable app_chanisavail --enable app_chanspy \
...
make
make install WGET_EXTRA_ARGS="--no-verbose"
make config
popd
```

Comment: how to go with default options?... @mikenn32

Comment: No idea. Maybe just don't run `menuselect/menuselect` at all?

Comment: yes... that's right  ```make menuselect.makeopts``` will keep default opts.useful for non-interactive shell scripting @miken32

Comment: Just not do make menuselect if you need default option. That step is not needed. You need only configure&make install if you not gooing change anything.